# Using IntelliJ IDEA with Oracle XE.. I dont see database or table?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, oracle11g

I am new to oracle and I am trying to use IntelliJ IDEA Database browser to see my data and my tables..

I did a basic install of oracle xe on my linux computer and the following java code does a insert and also will return all the data:

```
try {
            //step1 load the driver class
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

            //step2 create  the connection object
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "system", "xxx");

            //step3 create the statement object
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

            //step4 execute query
            Boolean ret = stmt.execute("insert into emp values (1, \'John\', 43)");

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");
            while (rs.next())
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + "  " + rs.getString(2) + "  " + rs.getString(3));

            //step5 close the connection object
            con.close();
```

but if I try to use IntelliJ IDEA database browser I dont see any XE dabase or my table.. but I am using the same connect data.

here is what I see on the screen

[image]

Can someone please tell me where I should be looking for my table and data.. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one Oracle XE database per machine.  Within that single database, you'll have a number of schemas.  Many of those schemas are installed by default (i.e. `SYS`, `SYSTEM`, etc.).  If you are coming from a different database product, what MySQL or SQL Server calls a "database" is most similar to what Oracle calls a "schema".

Based on the Java code you posted, it appears that you probably created an `EMP` table in the `SYSTEM` schema.  That is a bad idea-- you should never create new objects in the `SYS` or `SYSTEM` schema.  You should be creating a new schema to hold any new objects that you want to create.  In IntelliJ, it appears that you should be able to go to the `SYSTEM` schema to find your table and the data you inserted.  But, again, you shouldn't be creating objects in the `SYSTEM` schema in the first place.